# C++ reading and then editing a text file

Tags: c++, io, edit

I am wondering how to read in and edit a text file by searching for lines containing foobar and then erasing those lines only.  Don't need a full program, if someone could just point me towards the right fstream functions.

Comment: Of course, the obvious way is just `grep -v foobar your_file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class line {
    std::string data;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        std::getline(is, l.data);
        return is;
    }
    operator std::string() const { return data; }    
};

int main() {      
    std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<line>(std::cin),
                        std::istream_iterator<line>(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
                        [](std::string const &s) { 
                            return s.find("foobar") != std::string::npos;
                        });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is so enticing. I always enjoy the huge, one-statement solutions involving some form of `std::copy`.

Comment: @chris: It is a bit long, but primarily because it has `std::[io]stream_iterator<some_type>(some_stream)` three times over, and each of those (obviously enough) uses quite a few key-strokes. It is ultimately pretty simple though -- a function with four parameters.

Comment: Indeed. I personally think algorithms such as this are more clear as to what's being done.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
string sLine = "";
infile.open("temp.txt");

while (getline(infile, sLine))
{
  if (strstr(sLine, "foobar") != NULL)
    cout<<sLine;
  else
    //you don't want this line... it contains foobar
}

infile.close();
cout << "Read file completed!!" << endl;
```

here I have printed the output to the console, not back to the file, because this should point you in the right direction.

if you need a hint on how to print the lines to the file read below:

Save all the lines that don't contain foobar to a string. After you have read the whole file, close it, then open it with write permission and write the string to it. this will also overwrite the old content.

Comment: Thank you!!  I don't know why I didn't think of outputting to a new file.  Cheers.

Comment: Can you also explain why please?

Comment: I have modified the code. the link you gave me does not explain why it doesn't work though. it just proposes alternatives.

Comment: @IonutHulub, Perhaps [this one](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-eof.html) is any better?

Comment: It's an issue of that not being the proper way of doing it and it could lead to unexpected behavior for you. So it's best to just steer clear of it. I like the while(std::getline(inputfile, somestring)) way of doing it because it's easy to see what's happening. As long as you can keep successfully reading lines from the file, you can work with them.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably edit that blog post. It fails because `eof()` only becomes true *after* reading has failed. After you read the last line, it's still false, so you try to read (and process) more -- but that read fails, so you process the line you previously read again. The result is that your code appears to read the last line twice.